# Is PHP loadXML vulnerable to XXE attack (and to other attacks)? Is there a list of vulnerable functions?

Tags: php, attacks, xml, xxe

I have PHP code that uses the loadXML function (as well as other XML functions).

1. Is the loadXML function vulnerable to XXE attack? Namely, if the XML contains external entities, will they be interpreted?
2. Is this function vulnerable to other XML based attacks? E.g., the Billion Laughs DoS attack?
3. Can you refer me to a list of functions that are vulnerable to XXE and to other XML-related attacks?

I know that it is possible to easily block XXE attacks in PHP by changing the settings. Yet, I will be glad to get answers to the questions I raised.

Comment: Some of these like the DoS attack can easily be tested by yourself.

Comment: Being it PHP, I can give a much shorter lists of functions that are *not* vulnerable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is the loadXML function vulnerable to XXE attack? Namely, if the XML contains external entities, will they be interpreted?

By default, no.

External Entities are not parsed without `LIBXML_NOENT` being set. If `libxml_disable_entity_loader` is set to true, not even `LIBXML_NOENT` will allow XXE.

> Is this function vulnerable to other XML based attacks? e.g., the Billion Laughs DoS attack?

No, billion laughts will be caught with default settings:

```
DOMDocument::loadXML(): Detected an entity reference loop in Entity
```

What will not be caught is [quadratic blowup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212752/how-can-i-use-phps-various-xml-libraries-to-get-dom-like-functionality-and-avoi). Note that the entities need to actually be substituted, which is either done via the [rather poorly named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807506/what-does-libxml-noent-do-and-why-isnt-it-called-libxml-ent) `LIBXML_NOENT` or by simply accessing the node (eg via  `textContent`).

Comment: The name of this flag is so horribly confusing, as is the complete lack of official documentation.

Comment: @Polynomial: Welcome to PHP.

Comment: @WillihamTotland PHP is pretty awful regarding naming and documenting. But `noent` is already present in [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (at least as parameter in their command line tool, and the other bindings such as ruby use the same flag as well).

Comment: @tim A poorly named, poorly document flag that _can't_ be blamed on PHP? Frankly, I never thought I'd see the day. ;)

Comment: An example of quadratic blowup: [the billion lulz attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs).

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Sure, it's a question of definition, which isn't always 100% clear. You could - as wikipedia does, and which does make sense - say that quadratic blowup is a variant of billion laughs. But often the specific attack which uses nested entities is called billion laughs, and the other variant is called quadratic blowup ([the source wikipedia cites](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities) does this for example).

Comment: Wait... you say the "billion laughs" attack will be caught by the parser because it contains a circular reference, but then you say it's vulnerable to quadratic blowup.  The "billion laughs" attack doesn't contain any circular references; it's a quadratic blowup issue.

Comment: @MasonWheeler no, it doesn't contain circular references, but nested references, which are caught. quadratic blowup doesn't contain nested references, but just the same reference over and over, which isn't caught.